# Eslint not working in VSCode for Next.js in a monorepo setup

Tags: next.js, eslint, monorepo

I have a monorepo project for a full stack application. Two services that I'm working on right now are NestJs API and Next.js ssr/frontend.

My folder structure is as follows:

```
services/
  api-main/
     .eslintrc.js
     //nestjs project files
  ssr/
     .eslintrc.json
     //next.js project files
```

So as you can see they use separate configurations, each auto-generated by their respective bootstrappers (@nest/cli and create-next-app).

I've also added both these locations to the eslint working directories settings:

```
{
  "eslint.workingDirectories": ["./services/ssr", "./services/api-main"]
}
```

Eslint apparently works for the NestJS part but not for the Next.js part. Even when I run `npm run lint` or `npx eslint services/ssr/src`, I get no errors regardless of whether there are any errors or not (I've tested this by intentionally creating unused variables). Also the ESLint output shows no errors whatsoever, as if everything is working. The eslint config for Next.js is, as mentioned, auto-generated and very minimal:

```
{
  "extends": "next/core-web-vitals"
}
```

I've tried googling this extensively but every article/thread says that the eslint working directories setting should fix it, but apparently it's not the case here.

I'm not sure whether it's relevant but the development is set up through docker, however node_modules (and all the project files) are bind-mounted so it shouldn't present a problem.

Any ideas? Thanks.